# Open GL ES - Difference between GLenum vs Glint and GLint vs GLsizei

Tags: types, opengl-es

There's a datatype in Open GL called GLenum which can hold from 0 up to 4,294,967,295. Anywhere I've seen it used I've never found any difference between it and GLInt. And another datatype that I cannot understand is GLsizei because it's completely the same as Glint(at least it seems so.) What are the uses of GLenum and GLsizei and how are they different from Glint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names kinda give away the purpose. `GLenum` is for enums. `GLsizei` is for sizes. These aren't complicated concepts here. OpenGL is simply providing some semantic association between values and types.

If a function takes a `GLenum`, then you should pass one of the `GL_...` enumerators to it. If it takes a `GLsizei`, you should pass a size. They are different from `GLint` in that they *mean something different*, not that they're bigger or smaller.

Size doesn't matter; it's what you do with it that counts.

Comment: Let's say a function expects GLsizei.What would be different if it expected Glint? After all Glint and GLsizei are exactly the same things. Then why would a function prefer to take either of them?

Comment: @MikeJM: Because it *means something different*. You could have all your functions in C++ take `void*`s and dispense with the type system altogether. That doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: What I can infer from your comment is that when OpenGL sees GLsizei behaves differently from the way it would if it saw Glint. It's kind of an instruction to Open GL as to how to handle certain tasks. Am I correct?

Comment: @MikeJM: No, when *you* see `GLsizei`, *you* behave differently towards that parameter by putting *sizes* in that field.